# display a message if get form is empty

Tags: forms

I have a CPT, where i made a filter by taxonomies. Its a simple form, where users can filter by 2 taxonomies.
If the filter returns no posts because its empty i want to show a message (ex. "Sorry no Events found")

And if its possible, i want to show (after form is submitted) the filter options, which were chosen by the user. I know how i could show this with method=post, but i dont have any idea for method=get.

Thanks for help, thats what i coded so far.

```
    <div class="leweb_events_search">
     <form method="get" action=""> 
        <div class="leweb_select">
        <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'events_category', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

                echo '<select name="events_category"><option value="">Select category...</option>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                endforeach;
                echo '</select>';
            endif;
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="leweb_select">
        <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'events_car', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

                echo '<select name="events_car"><option value="">Select category...</option>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                endforeach;
                echo '</select>';
            endif;
        ?>  
        </div>

 <input type="button" value="submit">       

     </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: And what code do you use to get events?

Comment: "I know how i could show this with method=post, but i dont have any idea for method=get" I don't see the difference in this context. What are you having trouble with? You just need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` .

Comment: This is so embarrassing, sorry for that post...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem, its easy to display a message with have_posts()

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    echo "Events gefunden";
} else {
    echo "Keine Events gefunden";
}
?>
```